# JPQL SELECT Query with where clause returning same row when it hits more than one result for the where clause in table

Tags: jpa, orm, persistence, jpql, dto

My table has 2 primary keys: id and theme

The query :
@NamedQuery(name = "Theme.findByID", query = "select t from Theme t where t.id = :id")

And suppose, if a particular id has 4 rows of data, the list I get is of size 4 but with the data of row 1 in all 4 places.

TypedQuery tQuery = em.createNamedQuery("Theme.findByID", Theme.class);
        tQuery.setParameter("id", id);

```
    List<Theme> resultList = (List<Theme>)tQuery.getResultList();

    System.out.println("size of list : " + resultList.size());//returns 4

    resultList.forEach(System.err::println);/* is returning data in row 1 for the particular id 4 times*/
```

What is going wrong here?

Comment: Did you map the id as THE id in JPA, or as part of a composite pk that you seem to have on the database?  Show your entity and the mappings.

Comment: But I have to select using id only, all the themes in the table for that id. How will I write my query if I make a pk class of id and theme? I have no value to supply for theme.

Comment: I don't understand your issue.   If it isn't unique, it is not an ID.  Your class has a theme and id column, and both are used to uniquely identify your object/row in the database, so you need to specify that JPA use both to uniquely identify your Entity.  Specifying both in JPA does not change how you have to use your application or JPA at all, and you still can query by the id field as you are.  The id class only affects what you pass to the em.find method.  Try it first.

Comment: Yes I made a composite pk class with overridden hashcode() and equals() method. Works well now! All the data is coming properly now.  Thanks much1